# Prevent HTML5 validation on a field specific basis

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am looking to prevent HTML5 based validation dynamically on a field specific basis through JavaScript.

I have a form which will have multiple input fields which use HTML5 validation. The fields dynamically appear or hide based on the settings in related fields.

I would like to turn off HTML5 validation for the hidden fields temporarily just before the form submit event. I have tried the following but this did not appear to alter the willValidate property.

```
    $('input:hidden').each(function(){
    $(this).prop('willValidate',false);
});
```

I have come up with a work around which I feel is messy. It involves adding classes for each of the properties and for the pattern property storing this in an extra data-pattern property and then adding and removing the appropriate properties at the point of submitting based on their visibility.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: can u show me the html part?

Comment: if these input fields are disabled, HTML5 validation should ignore them

Answer (score 2):

I would try:

```
$('input:hidden').each(function(){
   $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

then validate your form. The hidden inputs should be ignored

Comment: This is a good answer, however, I actually want to submit the hidden data as it is. Disabling will prevent the data from being submitted at all.